# Paypal ограничить время на платеж для пользователя

Tags: php, paypal

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, не знаю как реализовать следующую логики оплати, после бронирование слота у пользователя есть 10 минут для оплати если он не оплачивает в течении 10 минут слот становится доступным для заказа другими пользователями. 
Есть ли возможность ограничить в paypal время оплаты после истечении которого пользователь не сможет оплатить заказ?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого в нужно указать payKeyDuration в вашем PayRequest'e

Вот выдержка из [PayPal API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/):

```
xs:duration (Optional) The duration for which the pay key returned by this request is valid. After this period, the pay key expires. If no pay key duration is supplied, it defaults to 3 hours. Valid values for this field are from 5 minutes to 30 days.
```